# Pandas Dataframe Select rows based on values from a lookup dataframe and then another condition based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Kinda new to python, Have this algo where I am trying to extract values from df1 based on the lookup df2 ( which has the target values).

```
df 1
A     B     C    D
a     b     10   2
a     a     20   4
b     a     40   10
a     b     5    5
b     a     10   1
```

```
df 2
A     B     C  
a     b     15  
a     a     30  
b     a     20  
z     x     5   
x     y     10
```

Need to return rows from df1 based on value in df2 which means 
if for col[A,B] value[C] is less than value[C] in using lookup df2 for col[A,B]

So, read DF1 - Row 1 - I get a,b and c=10 - use that to lookup limit for a,b in DF2 where I get value of Col[c] as 15 - so add this row to the new DF.. But when I read row 4 which is b,a c=40 which is more that df2[b,a]c=15 - so false for that row.

So the return df should be

```
df 1
A     B     C    D
a     b     10   2
a     a     20   4
a     b     5    5
b     a     10   1
```

I have it implemented but looks pretty rudimentary and may not be very efficient either. Any suggestions.. I was hoping to use the df1.apply and lambda but not very sure how to. But again if there a better way to do would like your comments.

This snippet shows how I was able to get it to work - not the optimal solution

```
     __sdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaabbbcccc'), 'B': list('ababsbcdcd'), 'c': range(10), 'd': range(0, 20, 2),
                              'g': [1] * 3 + [2] * 3 + [3] * 4})
        print "orig : \n {0}".format(__sdf)
        __qf = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaabbczz'), 'B': list('abybsdxy'), 'c': list('23567894')})
        print "qf : \n {0}".format(__qf)
        keys = ['A', 'B']
        col_c = 'c'
        i1 = __sdf.set_index(keys).index
        i2 = __qf.set_index(keys).index
        __relevant_qf = __qf[i2.isin(i1)]
        print "relevant qf : \n {0}".format(__relevant_qf)

        i10 = __sdf.set_index(keys).index
        __new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for idx, row in __relevant_qf.iterrows():
            data = []
            __q_val = float(row['c'])
            data.append(row[keys])
            __res_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            i20 = __res_df.set_index(keys).index
            __sub_df = __sdf[i10.isin(i20)]
            print "__sub_df : \n {0}".format(__sub_df)
            __sub_df = __sub_df.loc[__comp(__sub_df[col_c], __q_val)]
            print "filtered __sub_df : \n {0}".format(__sub_df)
            __new_df = __new_df.append(__sub_df)
        print "__new_df : \n {0}".format(__new_df)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a join on the two dataframes?

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I updated it with the sample working code

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you my input based on the result you expect to see:

What you could do is merge and then filter on it.

```
data = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['A','B'])
data = data[data['C_x']<data['C_y']]
data = data[['A','B','C_x','D']]
```

**Result**:

```
    A   B   C_x D
0   a   b   10  2
1   a   b   5   5
2   a   a   20  4
4   b   a   10  1
```

Is this what you were expecting to do?

Comment: Thanks @Gayatri. For some reason the filter is not working for me - data = data[data['C_x']<data['C_y']] not sure what am I missing

Comment: Can you see the columns C_x and C_y after merge?

Comment: Also check the data types of the columns if they are int64.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, one was an int the other an str. Thank You @Gayatri for your help - this is certainly way better than what I have. Only question I have is - would creating a new merged DF be okay if we have a large dataset to be merged? That was the reason I was trying to filter from existing dataframes.

Comment: As far as know, merge should be fast even for pretty big dataframes.Please upvote my answer if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: Sure @Gayatri. Did upvote - but wouldn't show since I am a new user.

Comment: Got ya :) No Problem.